# How to insert filename php value into javascript?

Tags: php

Hello i got code where i put my images in array

```
<?php

foreach (array_merge(glob("NU/*.[jJ][pP][gG]"),glob("NU/*.[pP][nN][gG]"),glob("NU/*.[jJ][pP][eE][gG]"),glob("NU/*.[gG][iI][fF]")) as $filename) {
}

?>
```

and i got javascript where i must use this $filename! how can i put this value in javascript operations? some example would be welcome and appreciated ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
print "<script type=text/javascript>var foo=$foo</script>";
?>
```

All the usual caveats about the safety of code injection and string escaping apply.

Comment: But if i got separated javascript file from php file?